# Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:15.0.0]

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, build-dependencies, gradle-dependencies

I am trying to open existing android project in Android Studio and `gradle` cannot build the app and it shows the error as:

**Error : strong text Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:15.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.firebase.codelab.mlkit_custommodel"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:15.0.0'
 }
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

As **AS** suggests `could not find method implementation() for arguments` which means the gradle does not recognize your implementation in gradle. It implies that you are using an old version of gradle, when compile method was used.

*NOTE:*

> **So, the solution is to update your gradle to the latest version and
>   try again. Method `implementation` is supported in versions 3.4 or
>   later.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
targetSdkVersion 28
com.google.firebase: firebase-ml-model-interpreter: 16.0.0
```

And I don't have this problem. Try to update the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.0.0'
```

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) more informations.

Please also update in your build.gradle file (project), the following dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Update gradle and

then:

in **build.grade(app)**:

```
replace compile -> implementation

repace androidTestCompile ->androidTestImplementation

replace testCompile ->testImplementation
```

in **build.grade(project)**:

```
    allprojects {
       repositories {
        jcenter()
        google() // Google's Maven repository . add this line here<br>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment or delete this line: ***implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'***
the project will build and run - work your way up from here.

This is what worked for me.